# With Buildship 2 subprojects are not linked as Project Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, build.gradle, buildship

For several months we've been using Buildship 1.X plus some manual .launch/tasks to build our Eclipse/WTP config files per development environment.  I am currently attempting to migrate to using Buildship 2 (which I'm hoping will rid us of the need for the manual bits.)

However, when I import the projects (which have 0 eclipse config files at this point) via the buildship/gradle import, the subprojects are included via 'Libraries' rather than as 'Projects' (see image below.)  In contrast, if I use gradle's eclipse task to generate the eclipse config files (i.e. .classpath) then the configuration ends up as I would expect it to be.  Is this a current limitation of Buildship, or do I need to do something differently in my gradle files to coerce Buildship to bring them in as Projects?

Ultimately I don't know that I should care about this difference, but I do know that I'm getting compiler errors saying classes from the subprojects are missing from the classpath.  As long as I can fix that issue, I'm perfectly happy.

[image: opposite of what I expected to see]

**Potentially helpful info**

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'projectroot'

include 'Project2.0'
project(':Project2.0').name = 'projectx'
include 'the-platform'
include 'the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-common'
include 'the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-model'
include 'the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-persist'
include 'the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-service'
```

Project2.0/build.gradle (snippet):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-common')
    compile project(':the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-model')
    compile project(':the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-persist')
    compile project(':the-platform:central-repo:central-repo-service')
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, nevermind.  My intuition about the difference between the behavior of buildship vs the eclipse plugin to gradle being responsible for my classpath issues was incorrect.  Something else (as yet unexplained) must've been the issue as it is working correctly now.